# Why ng-show,ng-message are always displaying?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm in trouble with a quite simple situation.I'm trying to show an error message in a form when inserting incorrect value;the strange thing is that searching on the web I'm doing the right thing,but I've all messages always showing. Here is the code:

```
<form name="regForm" ng-controller="loginController as ctrl">
    <fieldset>
        <legend> Registration Form </legend>
        <div>
            <label for='name' > Name </label>
            <input id='name' name='name' ng-model="form.name" type="text" required ng-minlength="3">
            <div ng-messages="regForm.name.$error" 
                 ng-if="regForm.name.$dirty">
                <div ng-message="required">This field is required</div>
                <div ng-message="minlength">This field must be over 3 characters</div>
            </div>

        </div>
         <div>
            <label for='surname' > Surname </label>
            <input id='surname' name='surname' ng-model="form.surname" type="text" required ng-minlength="3" >
        </div>
         <div>
            <label for='personalId' > Personal badge id </label>
            <input id='personalId' name='personalId' ng-model="form.id" type="text" required>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for='email'> E-mail </label>
            <input id='email' name='email' ng-model="form.mail" type="email" required>
        </div>
         <div>
            <label for='emailOK' > Confirm e-mail </label>
            <input id='emailOK' name='emailOK'ng-model="form.mail2" type="email" ng-match="form.mail" >
          <span ng-show="(regForm.email.$modelValue !== regForm.emailOK.$modelValue) 
            && regForm.email.$touched
            && !regForm.emailOK.$error.required">Email does not match.</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for='pwd'> Password </label>
            <input id='pwd' name='pwd' ng-model="form.password" type="password" >
        </div>
         <div>
            <label for='pwdOK' > Confirm password </label>
            <input id='pwdOK' name='pwdOK' ng-model="form.password2" type="password" ng-pattern="form.password" >
            <span ng-show="regForm.pwdOK.$error.pattern">Passwords have to match!</span>
        </div>


        <input type='button' value='submit' ng-click="check(this)" style='margin-left: 90px'>
```

I'm trying both ng-show,ng-message but they don't work as expected,could anyone help me?Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"they don't work as expected"* .. we don't know what expectations are or what is happening. Provide proper problem description along with expected behaviors. A demo will definitely help also

Comment: take off $modelValue in your boolean

Comment: @charlietfl I expect that the div or the ng-message are showed once I write something,not when I load the page;in particular for the confirmation email,the span should appear once the two values are different,but this is not happening here. Rafael,just taken off but nothing is changed.

Comment: Please show your controller. Who knows if your controller is really called loginController and You are using aliases, but you are not using your alias in your view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

It looks like you have 2 concepts confused. Angular only cares about the HTML form and input name when it is applying styles for `$required`, `$dirty`, `$pristine`, and the like...not when you are looking for input values.

When you are comparing input values, you need to reference what you put in the `ng-model` directive.

- Remove `$modelValue`
- Fix your reference errors

You are binding your input elements to `form.mail2` and `form.mail`.

Replace with

```
<span ng-show="(form.mail !== form.mail2) && regForm.email.$touched && !regForm.emailOK.$error.required">Email does not match.</span>
```

#### My advice to you...

You might want to start off with `ng-show="(form.mail !== form.mail2)` and build onto your expression from there...

Comment: I've done as you said,but no changes.The text email does not match remains even when I type two identical emails.

Comment: `!regForm.emailOK.$error.required` something does not look correct with this part in your boolean.

Comment: You also are using **controller aliases** which can attribute to further reference issues in your code. I cant really help you without seeing your controller.

Comment: I've put just (form.mail !== form.mail2) without the other check,but it doesn't work.My controller is empty at the moment,I've just the module var app = angular.module('app', ['ngMessages']); I need the controller when I resolve all this stuff.

Comment: you are using an alias for your controller called `ctrl`. Therefore, you should be using `ctrl.form.mail` and `ctrl.form.mail2`. Also in your controller you will need `this.form = {}`

Comment: Not working,thanks for the help,I guess I've to go deeper in studying ow it works,thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Sorry about not having enough reputation so I post this as an answer.

**Objects need to be initialized before assigning them to form members**

**JavaScript**

```
angular.module('somemodule').controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.testForm = {};
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form name="testForm" ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
    <div>
        <label for='surname' > Surname </label>
        <input id='surname' name='surname' ng-model="testForm.surname" type="text" required ng-minlength="3" >
    </div>
    <span ng-show="testForm.surname.$valid">Oh! Your surname seems good</span>
</form>
```

Object name is advised to be same to the form name to avoid messing up.